# Installing .ipa onto iphone using iTunes

Tags: ios, iphone, ipa

I have successfully copied over the .ipa file into iTunes then installed it on my iPhone5. However, the app icon on the phone is actually greyed out a bit and I can't actually open the app. Do you know what that would mean? When I click on the app to open it the app name changes to "Installing..." but nothing actually happens - it remains greyed out.

Comment: This way maybe work on jailbreak device

Comment: How did you create the IPA, did you build the app with an Ad-Hoc provisioning profile? Did you archive it via Xcode?

Comment: It was just sent to me in an email. Not sure how it was built